# Maximum characters and minimum

Tags: php, html, forms

So i have an form, with phonenumber, zipcode etc.

What I want to do is restrict the user from typing in a max of 5 for example.
The only thing i've seen, is that you can only do this with numbers (`<input type="number">`)

I hope someone can help me!
Cheers,
Jesse

Comment: You mean this.. `<input type="text" name="text" maxlength="5"`

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this,

An  element with a maximum length of 5 characters: `maxlength="5"`

```
  <input type="number" name="yourname" maxlength="5">
```

If want like Range (between 1 and 5):

```
  <input type="number" name="yourname" min="1" max="5">
```

Answer (score 0):

You can restrict the user from entering the above the maximum characters by using `maxlength` property for a text box.

```
 <input type="text" name="sample" maxlength="5">
```

Answer (score 0):

You can limit the characters by specifying the `maxlength` property.

```
  <input type="number" id="Textbox" name="Textbox" maxlength="10" />
```

For phone numbers maxlength would be 10.

Answer (score 0):

Another method of doing this, aside from the HTML form alone. Is if they enter more than the preferred amount of characters. Just read between the character numbers you are looking for.

```
$formVar = substr($_POST['number'], 0, 4)
```

That will get only the first through fifth character. Useful if people try to tamper data past the HTML limitation.

Answer (score 0):

There are two attributes:

- `size` restricts the **minimum** of characters displayed
- `maxlength` the **maximum** of characters that can be inputed.

Example:

```
<input type="text" name="sample" maxlength="5" size="3">
```